# Read value from HTML node

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I'm new to XML/HTML-parsing. Don't even know the right words to do a proper search for duplicates.

I have this HTML file which looks like this:

```
<body id="s1" style="s1">
    <div xml:lang="uk">
        <p begin="00:00:00" end="00:00:29">
          <span fontFamily="SchoolHouse Cursive B" fontSize="18">I'm great!</span>
        </p>
```

Now I need `00:00:00`, `00:00:29` and `I'm great!` from it. I could read it like this:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(file);
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
        continue;

    if (reader.LocalName != "p")
        continue;

    var a = reader.GetAttribute(0);
    var b = reader.GetAttribute(1);

    if (reader.LocalName == "span")
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        XmlNode elem = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
        var c = elem.InnerText;
    }
 }
```

I get values in variables `a`, `b` and `c`. But there was a slight change in HTML format. **Now the HTML looks like this:**

```
<body id="s1" style="s1">
  <div xml:lang="uk">
      <p begin="00:00:00" end="00:00:29">I'm great! </p>
```

In this scenario how do I parse out `00:00:00`, `00:00:29` and `I'm great!` ? I tried this:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(file);
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
        continue;

    if (reader.LocalName != "p")
        continue;

    var a = reader.GetAttribute(0);
    var b = reader.GetAttribute(1);

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(reader);
    XmlNode elem = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
    var c = elem.InnerText;
}
```

But I get this error: `This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.` at line `doc.Load(reader)`. How to read correctly and what's causing the trouble? I am using .NET 2.0

Comment: Take a look at [html agility pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), seems like what you need to parse html.

Comment: @oleksii should I really use third party lib when there's plenty under System.Xml? Moreover I am not doing anything related to html

Comment: It is clear that XML != HTML, I thought html agility pack will be useful if you do any html parsing, as you seem to have some html in the sample. If you don't work with html, then maybe take a look at LINQ-to-XML.

Comment: @oleksii: With that comment I meant the op, not you :) I basically just confirmed what you said.

Comment: Can someone edit the title of the question accordingly? I am not very sure when this XML sounds like HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have HTML that you want to parse with a XML parser. That may also be the reason why you get the `This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.` exception: because you have more than one root node, which is allowed (or better: tolerated) in HTML, but not XML.

Use an HTML parser instead. Unfortunatelly there is nothing built-in within the .NET framework. You have to take a third party library for that. A very good one is the [HTML agility pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex), that oleksii already mentioned in his comment.

**Edit:**

From your comments, I get the feeling your not familiar with the fact that there is no direct relation between HTML and XML. The graphic taken from [here](http://www.jbi.hio.no/bibin/dill/summer_school/2009/xml-wellformed.html) illustrates this quite well:

[image: Relation between SGML, HTML and XML]

Neither is XML a subset of HTML, nor the other way around. Only if you have strict XHTML (rarely the case), you have an HTML document that can be parsed with an XML parser. But be aware if there is some mistake in the code of such an XHTML document, the parser will fail, while a common browser will continue to display the page. Also, the future of XHTML is quite unclear, now that HTML5 is comming to life slowly but steadily...

*To sum up:* To avoid all those pitfalls, take the easy road and go for an HTML parser.

Comment: There is nothing that can be done to parse using .NET XML classes?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly not. HTML is not a subset of XML. Also, due to HTML parsers (also those used in browsers) being *much* more tolerant when it comes to parsing invalid input, people started writing invalid HTML for websites or just didnt care about validity. However, XML parsers expect *strictly valid* input, if not, they quit parsing and throw exceptions like you have seen.

Comment: Can you edit the title of the question accordingly? I am not very sure when this XML sounds like HTML

Comment: @nawfal: edited the title and corrected the tags of your question

Answer (score 3):

Since you are wanting to parse HTML, you could use `WebClient` (or `WebBrowser`) to load the page and then use the HTML DOM to navigate through it. You need to add a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library` (COM) for the following code example:

```
  string html;
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(new Uri("http://www.google.com")))
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
  IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)new HTMLDocument();
  doc.write(html);
  foreach (IHTMLElement el in doc.all)
    Console.WriteLine(el.tagName);
```

I have tried loading HTML into XML before, and its all too hard - fixing up unclosed tags (like <BR>), putting quotes around attributes, giving attributes without values a value, etc. Since I wanted to then use XSLT against it, after loading into the HTML DOM and navigated through it creating the relevant XML node for each HTML node. Then I had a proper XML representation of the HTML.